# sql server - xml query - concat - adding space

Tags: sql-server, xml, qxmlquery

I want to take a xml string and convert it to sql-table semicolon-delimitate

```
declare @x xml --for example
set @x = '<root><row><a>a1</a><b>b2</b></row><row><a>aa1</a><b>bb2</b></row></root>'
SELECT T.c.query('.').query('for $i in row/*/text() return concat($i,";")').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS result  
FROM   @x.nodes('root/row') T(c)
```

**The Result:**

```
a1; b2;
aa1; bb2;
```

**The Result I want:** (no space)

```
a1;b2;
aa1;bb2;
```

*>> Bonus: Remove last semicolon*

```
a1;b2
aa1;bb2
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done much easier:

```
DECLARE @xml XML='<root>
  <row>
    <a>a1</a>
    <b>b2</b>
  </row>
  <row>
    <a>aa1</a>
    <b>bb2</b>
  </row>
</root>';

SELECT (
      STUFF(
      (
          SELECT ';' + v.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
          FROM r.nodes('*') AS B(v)
          FOR XML PATH('')
      ),1,1,'')
      )
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/row') AS A(r)
```

Comment: Fantastic! :) Thank you!

Comment: How can I sort the result? etc, first value 'aa1' in <a> column?

Comment: @inon Try `ORDER BY v.value('.','nvarchar(max)')` before the `FOR XML`

Comment: It sort the columns, not the rows... :(

Comment: @inon, sorry, I don't understand this... Do you want to sort after the element's name? In this case use `local-name(.)` instead of the single `.`.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `REPLACE`, `REVERSE`, and `STUFF` is how i was able to achieve this:

```
declare @x xml --for example
set @x = '<root><row><a>a1</a><b>b2</b></row><row><a>aa1</a><b>bb2</b></row></root>'
SELECT reverse(stuff(reverse(replace(T.c.query('.').query('for $i in row/*/text() return concat($i,";")').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), ' ', '')), 1, 1, '')) AS result  
FROM   @x.nodes('root/row') T(c)
```

There might be a better way to get rid of the spaces since this would also replace any spaces in the XML node values as well.

Comment: Good! but, It's remove also spaces within cell. I changed to Replace(....,'; ',';') see my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @x xml --for example
set @x = '<root><row><a>a1</a><b>b2</b></row><row><a>aa1</a><b>bb2</b></row></root>'
SELECT reverse(stuff(reverse(replace(T.c.query('.').query('for $i in row/*/text() return concat($i,";")').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), '; ', ';')), 1, 1, '')) AS result  
FROM   @x.nodes('root/row') T(c)
```